# Add active class in CI admin panel

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, sidebar

I have divided Header, Footer and Sidebar for admin panel. I have apply links in sidebar as per my need. The problem is my admin URL is example.com/admin (sidebar dashboard menu link) and settings url is example.com/admin/settings. Now, when I clicked on dashboard from sidebar 'active' class added into all sidebar menu link which have example.com/admin/{next_url_path}. I am developing admin panel in Codeigniter how can I resolve this error?

**sidebar.php**

```
<nav class="sidebar sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <?php echo anchor('admin', '<span class="menu-title"><i class="mdi mdi-home menu-icon"></i> Dashboard</span>', 'class="nav-link"'); ?>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#settings" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="settings">
        <span class="menu-title">
          <i class="mdi mdi-settings menu-icon"></i> Settings
        </span>
        <i class="menu-arrow"></i>
      </a>
      <div class="collapse" id="settings">
        <ul class="nav flex-column sub-menu">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <?php echo anchor('admin/settings', 'Settings', 'class="nav-link"'); ?>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <?php echo anchor('admin/activityLog', 'Activity Log', 'class="nav-link"'); ?>
          </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**js for adding active class**

```
var current = location.pathname.split("/").slice(-1)[0].replace(/^\/|\/$/g, '');
$('.nav li a', sidebar).each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if (current === "") {
    //for root url
    if ($this.attr('href').indexOf(current) !== -1) {
      $(this).parents('.nav-item').last().addClass('active');
      if ($(this).parents('.sub-menu').length) {
        $(this).closest('.collapse').addClass('show');
        $(this).addClass('active');
      }
    }
  } else {
    //for other url
    if ($this.attr('href').indexOf(current) !== -1) {
      $(this).parents('.nav-item').last().addClass('active');
      if ($(this).parents('.sub-menu').length) {
        $(this).closest('.collapse').addClass('show');
        $(this).addClass('active');
      }
    }
  }
})
```